# Can i add a XsltListViewWebPart in a default.aspx page?What do i need to have on a page to add it

Tags: sharepoint-designer

How can i add a WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart to a default.aspx page.I tried adding it to Sitepages folder by creating a page under sitepages > Datasources doubled click the list and i got a XsltListViewWebPart but not on a default.aspx page.

Also when i added a webpart zone and then tried to add XsltListViewWebPart it doesn't work.What are the requirements to add a XsltListViewWebPart  to a page.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to add it:

1. Through the Browser by the Edit Page option
2. Through Sharepoint Designer by the Add Webpart in the Advanced Edit
   Mode.
3. Through Code (Visual Studio)

Answer (score 0):

You can add WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart to default.aspx by editing this page only from browser.
However, you can make webpart page, make it home page and edit it from designer.